# SQL order results and then extract more than one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a SQL function. I would like to order all of the data from a table (any table, doesnt matter for this question). I would then like to order the data on one column. Then once this order has been performed I would like to extract a few of the columns from the top row (after the ordering).

I dont think I can use partititon by because the ordering is on the whole data, not groups of it?

Im stuck because you can only use ORDER BY at the end of a function

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Is it a table valued funtion?

Comment: [select top (n) * from any_table order by anything](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a complicated description of a `SELECT TOP 1` query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.ColumnA, t.ColumnD, t.ColumnF
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY t.ColumnB DESC,
```

Would order the table by `ColumnB` in descending order, then return Columns `A`, `D` and `F`.

I'm not sure you even need a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_dummy()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (

SELECT TOP 1
    name, object_id, type_desc
FROM sys.tables
ORDER BY create_date DESC)
```